# Setting a ServerName in the VirtualHost of Apache server is not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have tried to create a new Virtual Host in my Apache server, but I cannot address it by its new ServerName "mysite.game".
Can you spot any mistake in my code, please?

**OUTPUT**
What happens is that the URL **http://localhost:8081/** is displaying the right website directory, while "http://mysite.game" is giving the same error **HTTP Error 404**.

**INPUT**
This is what i have done.
In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, i inserted the line:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.game
```

In http.conf I added:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8081 
Listen [::0]:8081
```

and

```
<Directory "C:\game">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf, I added:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:\game"
    ServerName mysite.game
    <Directory "C:\game">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does your errorlog say? What's in c:\game ?

Comment: p.s. use forward slashes for windows paths in httpd.conf

Comment: In c:\game there is my website, all the files.

The error log says: